# Setting up TFS on VM in Azure

Tags: azure

I'm trying to setup a Team Foundation Server on Windows Server 2012 VM in Azure. I am able to use Visual Studio in the VM to connect to TFS, but when I tried using Visual Studio on my laptop to connect, I get the below error.

> "TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server"

I have created a TCP endpoint with name HTTP, public and private ports 8080, and checked that there is an inbound firewall rule on the VM for port 8080. Is there anything else I missed out?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

how are you accessing this server? S2S, natyive through the MYTFSSERVERNAME.cloudapp.net ? ow and is the webservice running? can you access it through the browser?

Comment: Ok I realized that my network is blocking port 8080, so I changed the public port to 80

Comment: Mike, this is not really an answer, you shall put such clarification questions as comments ;)